# Is it possible to sum an IloNumVar with a constant in java?

Tags: java, cplex

I am trying to sum an IloNumVar with a constant variable in java using Cplex library. The problem is that due to the difference between these variables, it is impossible to sum them. So I am wondering how it is possible to sum these two different variables. As I have known in Opl using Cplex, you can easily do this, but what about java? Is there any way for summing one IloNumVar (Decision Variable) with Constant java value?

do not share any trick for solving my problem.

```
    int [] a = new int [10];
    IloNumVar deltatest = model.numVar(3, 5);
    int m = 2;
```

how to assign the result to an Integer? For Example, I want to do this line.

```
     a[m+deltaset] = 1000;
```

I want to use the value of (m+deltaset) as an integer in other equations.

Comment: What is `deltaset`?

Comment: It is just a Descioun variable, and it is used in Cplex IBM for Optimization. After finishing the model, The value of these kinds of variables have been determined by Cplex

Comment: Do you want to access the index of ‘deltatest’? Or, are you wanting to access the solution value? Or, something else?

Comment: I want to use IloNumVar like deltaset as an index of an array to be able to modify that array

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you have in mind. There are two interpretations of your question:

1. You want to have an expression like `a[m + deltatest]` **in your model**, that is not possible with CPLEX (but you could use CP which allows that).
2. **After** the solve you want to use the value that CPLEX found for `deltatest`. In that case you can just to `a[m + Math.round(cplex.getValue(deltatest))]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, these solutions have not worked. Let me explain my problem in another way. I want to use IloNumVar as an index of an array. IloNumVar a = model.NumVar(3,5); IloNumVar [] b = model.NumVarArray(20,0,10); IloLinearExpr d d.addTerm(b[a],1);

Comment: Like I said, you are in case 1. This is not possible with CPLEX. You have two options: 1. You can use CP instead. 2. Given that your variable has only 3 possible values (3, 4, 5) you could create a temporary variable `tmp` and then add indicator constraints like `model.add(model.ifThen(a == 3, tmp == b[3]))`, `model.add(model.ifThen(a == 4, tmp == b[4]))` etc. With that you can then do `d.addTerm(tmp, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `a[m + deltatest]` exactly, but perhaps the following techniques will help.

First, you can create an array of variables and use the indices of that array to index into `a`. For example:

```
     final int NumVars = 10;
     int[] a = new int[NumVars];
     IloNumVar[] varArray = cplex.numVarArray(NumVars, 3, 5);
     int m = 2;

     for (int i = 0; i < (NumVars - m); ++i) {
        // i corresponds to the variable at varArray[i].
        a[m + i] = 1000;
     }
```

Alternately, you can construct a Map, like so:

```
     int[] a = new int[10];
     Map<IloNumVar, Integer> varMap = new Hashtable<IloNumVar, Integer>();
     int currentIndex = 0;
     IloNumVar deltatest = cplex.numVar(3, 5);
     varMap.put(deltatest, currentIndex++);
     int m = 2;

     a[m + varMap.get(deltatest)] = 1000;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these solutions have not worked. Let me explain my problem in another way. I want to use IloNumVar as an index of an array.
IloNumVar a = model.NumVar(3,5);
IloNumVar [] b = model.NumVarArray(20,0,10);
IloLinearExpr d
d.addTerm(b[a],1);